# How many threads in a loop

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

If I create a loop

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){//do something}
```

and run it through Visual Studio, will my program create a thread for every iteration, for the whole loop, or it's a variable number?

Comment: That all depends on what is in the body of the loop, by default no

Comment: A simple task like printing a number.

Comment: This is a normal loop, it won't create any threads. Are we missing some code here?

Comment: A separate thread will not be created unless you explicitly create one.

Comment: Visual C++ has a [`parallel_for`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505035.aspx) loop: [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728073.aspx)

Comment: as they said it, No. why should it? to be more specific, why do you think it would create threads?

Comment: @thebaconing I thought that processes create a thread everytime they want to do a specific smaller task.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc processes do. A for loop is not a process, it's a simple program control tool. It's up to the software writer to define what is to be in a new thread, not the system.

Comment: What threads are you seeing?  Perhaps whatever is doing the reporting is looking at something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and run it through Visual Studio, will my program create a thread for every iteration, for the whole loop, or it's a variable number?

None of the above.  Your program will by default have a single thread of execution and it will execute each iteration of the loop in series, without creating new ones.

Only with a feature like [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) (or similar) could you spawn different threads per iteration.

```
#include <omp.h>

#pragma omp parallel for
for(int n=0; n<10; ++n) { printf(" %d", n); }
printf(".\n");
```

Comment: Then what happens if I create a thread inside the loop, without synchronizing it? Will it print a number, then do whatever the thread asks in each loop?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc -- the same thing that happens with all threads that run in an unsynchronized manner.... whatever happens happens and it might not be the same every time.

Comment: This supplemental question depends very much on OpenMP's specification.  You should ask a new question regarding OMP specifically.  I suspect you can spawn new threads and they become independent of the tasks used by OMP.  However, the devil's in the details.  OMP offers scoping (or lifetime) rules that may impact how you end up storing a handle/context for the new thread, which may impact how you could robustly reap that thread later.

Comment: There is also [`#pragma loop( hint_parallel(n) )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh923901.aspx) but that is mostly just a hint to the compiler, not a guarantee